# how to use multiprocessing correctly to fill a matrix?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have an empty matrix that I create at the beginning of my code. This should be filled with correlation values. To speed up the process, I wanted to use multiprocessing.
But it doesn't seem to work very well. The functions calc_corr and also pool_initializer are not called. At least outputs within these functions are not displayed. Besides, the matrix is still just zeros at the end

```
# pool initializer function
def pool_initializer(result):
    i, j, new_matr = result
    corr_matrix[i, j] = new_matr[0,1]
    corr_matrix[j, i] = new_matr[1,0]



def calc_corr(i, j):
    sig1 = data_dict[i]['data']
    sig2 = data_dict[j]['data']
    nsig1 = sig1 - np.mean(sig1)
    nsig2 = sig2 - np.mean(sig2)
    corr = sp.signal.correlate(nsig1, nsig2, mode='same', method='fft')
    corr /= (len(sig2) * np.std(sig1) * np.std(sig2))
    max_corr = find_highest_peak(corr)
    temp_matrix = np.zeros((2,2))
    temp_matrix[0,1] = max_corr[1]
    temp_matrix[1,0] = max_corr[1]

    return (i, j, temp_matrix)



def find_highest_peak(data):
    data_array = np.array(data)
    highest_peak_index = np.argmax(data_array)
    highest_peak_value = data_array[highest_peak_index]
    return highest_peak_index,highest_peak_value




if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_dict = load_np_array_pickle('epoch_dict.pickle')[:300]
    start = time.perf_counter()
    corr_len = len(data_dict)
    corr_matrix = np.zeros((corr_len, corr_len))
    status_percentage = int(corr_len / 100) if corr_len > 100 else 1

    with Pool(processes=cpu_count()) as p:
        for i in range(corr_len):
            for j in range(i + 1, corr_len):
                p.apply_async(calc_corr, args=(i, j), callback=pool_initializer)
        p.close()
        p.join()

    end = time.perf_counter()
    print('Aufgebrachte Zeit:  {:.2f} s'.format(end - start, 2))
    print(corr_matrix)
```

Comment: Global variables aren't shared between different Python processes.

Comment: ok this worked. Thank you. 
Last question: Do I need the p.close() and p.join() at the end?

Comment: Yes. Leaving the with-block may`terminate` the worker processes before the work is finished, therefore you have to wait with `join` first which in turn requires `close`.

Comment: @alpa if you managed to fix your code, you should post it as an answer to your own question. It might help other people.